# storm-kafka Spout is retrieving the wrong offset

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

Using kafka 0.8.1.1 with their respective zookeeper and the current code of kafka-storm in https://github.com/apache/incubator-storm(last commit: 7ac24b893c) I had the following error:

> If I create two topics(topicA and topicB) and send data to
>   topicA(changing the offset of topicA to offsetA) and open a kafka
>   spout for topicA, everything is ok. But, if I open a spout for topicB,
>   the spout is retrieving the offset of the topicA, leading to a
>   Exception related to this wrong offset(offsetA instead of offsetB).

Inspecting the code in: https://github.com/apache/incubator-storm/blob/master/external/storm-kafka/src/jvm/storm/kafka/PartitionManager.java#L103, is retrieving the correct offsetB, but instead of using this variable, is using an offset found in a json. This json, is found in **/id/partition_0**(a zookeeper url) where both topics are being stored.

If I get the data from partition_0 from zookeeper, I receive the following information(beautified for readibility):

```
$ get /id/partition_0
{
"topology": {
    "id": "58e1c603-0ab0-4344-a614-204e4455e90a",
    "name": "Start test storm"
},
"offset": 1,
"partition": 0,
"broker": {
    "host": "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.compute.amazonaws.com",
    "port": 9092
},
"topic": "topicA"
}
 ...
```

As you can see, is giving the offset of topicA. This is the behaviour that I don't understand: If I'm retrieving the offset from the same url(**/id/partition_0**) for both topics, is obvious that for some topic, a wrong offset will be retrieved. Is something misconfigured in my zookeeper-kafka configuration? Is other the cause of this error?

I modified the code in that class(PartitionManager constructor) in order to ignore that json from **/id/partition_0** and using the offset from **KafkaUtils.getOffset(_consumer, spoutConfig.topic, id.partition, spoutConfig);** and my dataflow runs correctly.

If helps, I will also add the zookeeper information for both topics.

```
$ get /brokers/topics/topicA
{"version":1,"partitions":{"0":[0]}}
...


$ get /brokers/topics/topicB
{"version":1,"partitions":{"0":[0]}}
...
```

Comment: could you please try to set the `forceFromStart` to read from the beginning and see how it goes, just digging up the code and it seems that `_committedTo = KafkaUtils.getOffset(_consumer, spoutConfig.topic, id.partition, spoutConfig.startOffsetTime);` get called when `!topologyInstanceId.equals(jsonTopologyId) && spoutConfig.forceFromStart` returns true .. https://github.com/apache/incubator-storm/blob/master/external/storm-kafka/src/jvm/storm/kafka/PartitionManager.java#L87

Comment: I see, I will try it. I have one question: (line 88) Usually, what should be the value of spoutConfig.startOffsetTime? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Previously it used to be either -1 or -2 while the later indicate Kafka to read from the beginning .. but I guess from 0.8.* it accepts boolean ... so in that case it supposed to be true

Comment: But if the library reads every time since the beginning, would not lead to process a message twice in case that I execute this topology, shutdown, and execute it again?

Comment: I am very interested what you did in the end. I am also having problems with setting the starting offset.

Comment: How to fix this problems? @Juto and @ Gareve